# Detect move of mouse while clicked and detect doubleclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

for the moment I have implemented different actions for when a person clicks on a canvas and when a person clicks and drags something. I did this by binding the `mousedown` event to my canvas and in that function there is made the difference between a drag or a `mouseup`. This works very good, but I have a problem when I also want to support doubleclicking on elements.

The normal way to implement this is like this:

```
$(canvas).click(function1);
$(canvas).dblclick(function2);
```

but I didn't implemented that way because I had to check whether or not the mouse moved (i.e. dragged). This is my current implementation:

```
var handler = {
    clicked:function(e){
       ...
       $(canvas).bind('mousemove', handler.dragged);
       $(window).bind('mouseup', handler.dropped);
    },
    dragged:function(e){
       ...
    },
    dropped:function(e){
      function loop(ctr){
         if (ctr < 50) {
           setTimeout(function(){loop(ctr+1)}, 2);
           } else {
           $(canvas).mousedown(handler.clicked);
           handler.singleClick(e);
          }
      }
      $(canvas).mousedown(handler.doubleclicked);
      loop(0);
     },
     doubleClick: function(e){
       ...
     },
     singleClick: function(e){
       ...

         }                
   }

$(canvas).mousedown(handler.clicked);
```

I tried to combine those two things (recognition of dragging and doubleclick) by implementing the dropped-function which waits for a period of time to listen for another click and if it didn't occur within that period it goes to the `singleclick` function. For the moment this not yet recognizes the second click.

I assume that there exist better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this:
http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag

It provides you with additional functionality `.drag()` in addition to `.click()` and `.dblclick()`.

Theres also a drop version:
http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop

Comment: do you have any experience with this plugin? When I want to use it in my code I get an error from this piece of code from the plugin: `// toggles text selection attributes ON (true) or OFF (false)
 textselect: function( bool ){ 
  $( document )[ bool ? "unbind" : "bind" ]("selectstart", drag.dontstart )
   .attr("unselectable", bool ? "off" : "on" )
   .css("MozUserSelect", bool ? "" : "none" );
 }`
and I call it like the example: [http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drag/]

`$(div).bind('drag',function(event){alert("test");});`